# Can't boot Windows 7 of primary partition does not show in windows RE

Tags: windows-7, boot

Something's really messed up here.

I have a 750GB SATA drive primary partition is 250 MB 2nd partition is the rest.

Windows 7 is installed on the primary partition.

I can't boot into Windows; it just sends me to the recovery environment.

When I get to the system recovery options screen, no operating systems are listed.

I tried to go to load drivers and when I click on my computer the 
C drive is listed but with no usage stats.

D drive is listed (371GB of 454GB Free) displayed,

I can browse the data on the D drive but can't access the C drive at all.

I don't think its a physical problem with the disk, such as a hardware faliure, as both partitions are on the same disk.

Everything had been working fine, last thing I tried to do before this mess was to try and install .NET 4 client, i couldn't install it as it kept getting errors; I did a reboot and I am now in this mess.

I tried from the command prompt in the recovery console `BootCfg /scanOs` and no installations of windows were found.

Any ideas what I can do to get Windows back running???

I'm going to run startup repair overnight, but to be honset I don't think this will do anything as in the select operating system dialog when you first enter the recovery tools no operating systems are displayed, I really dont want to have to reinstall Windows again unless I can help it.

I just dont understand how the primary partition C drive can just stop working and the D partition be working ok???

From the command prompt I can `cd d:` and browse

If I try `cd c:` I get The parameter is incorrect...

UPDATE:

Startup repair has the message `repairing disk errors this might take over an hour to complete`

Fingers crossed this does the job, will see when I wake up tomorrow...

No joy 12 hrs later - is still attempting to fix disk errors on Operating system: Unknown on (Unknown) Local Disk

Another update:

When I go to reinstall Windows i get the screen 'Where do you want to reinstall Windows?'
with Disk0 partition 1 total size 243.8gb Freespace 243.8 GB type System
Disk 0 partition2: Data total size 154.5gb free space 371.0 GB Primary

So Windows can see the c drive when it wants to do an install

It however just shows me the circle cursor indicating its "thinking" wont let me select anything, click drive options nada....

Comment: You were trying to install windows 7 on a 250MB partition? Impossible! I'll assume its GB, anyways have you tried the following options using command prompt and boot exec by booting from the install CD or safe mode to get to a CMD:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/927392

Comment: Windows RE? You mean Windows PE right?

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled Windows and did manage to get access to the C drive eventually but there was no data on it.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

1. Shut down the PC, open it up and reseat your hard disk connector.
2. Turn on your PC and use Windows 7's built-in Repair faculties
3. If this doesn't work, insert the Windows 7 DVD and repair.
4. Finally, if this doesn't work, do a reinstallation on the same partition without formatting so that you can keep your data